# How to add Intellisense support to visual studio for new language

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I want to add Intellisense for .xyz file types which is my own language.
How should i proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own language services using the [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=30402623-93ca-479a-867c-04dc45164f5b).